# Postgres truncate command SQL: passing dynamic table name

Tags: python, postgresql

I am working on a Python web project using a `postgres` database as backend with the `psycopg2` package.

Earlier, I was trying `static` query for `truncate` command for demo purpose, after it works, I tried to make it  `dynamic`, thereby passing `table name`.

```
def clear_tables(query: str, vars_list: list[Any]):
   # psycog 2 connection engine code
   
   cursor.executemany(query=query, vars_list=vars_list)
   
   conn.commit()
   
   
def foo():

   vars_list: list[Any] = list()

   table_name: str = "person"

   record: tuple[Any] = (table_name,)

   vars_list.append(record)

   query = """
       TRUNCATE TABLE %s RESTART IDENTITY;
       """
     
   clear_tables(query=query, vars_list=vars_list)
```

On executing I am getting an error. Somehow the `table name` gets unwanted `'` single quotes

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'person'"
LINE 2:        TRUNCATE TABLE 'person' RESTART IDENTITY;
```

How to remove those quotes?

Comment: Use `%I` (Identifier) instead of `%s` (string) in your statement. So:  TRUNCATE TABLE %I RESTART IDENTITY;

Comment: I'm many years behind on PostgreSQL, but note that it's common in SQL databases for not all fields to be parameterizable in the first place. Part of the point of prepared statements is building a query plan _before_ you execute; but if you don't know which table, you can't look up which indices apply, and you otherwise don't have enough to start on planning. (Yes, that rationale doesn't apply to `TRUNCATE`, but in general, you aren't going to be letting untrusted code decide on a name of a table to truncate in the first place, so a lot of the reasoning _for_ prepared statements doesn't apply)

Comment: Hi Belayer, Thanks. I tried using it but somehow it didn't worked. On more searching, I got `AsIS` extension something from `psycog2`, I will try this now.

Comment: Hi Charles, Thanks. Well said and I agree with you. I am new to `sql`, I will like to learn and read on how to write good `postgres/sql` queries. Do you have or will like to suggest some `open source/free resources or code snippets`. As you mentioned, some components/parts of `sql` queries must not be parametrized, this make sense.

Comment: @Belayer `%I` and `%L` are placeholders used by the format() function available in Postgres. They don't work with Psycopg2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, and is safe against SQL injection:

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql


def truncate(conn: psycopg2.extensions.connection, schema: str, table: str):
    query = sql.SQL("TRUNCATE {schema}.{table} RESTART IDENTITY").format(
        schema=sql.Identifier(schema), table=sql.Identifier(table)
    )
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(query)


conn = psycopg2.connect()
truncate(conn, "public", "foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes and retry:

```
query = "TRUNCATE TABLE {tableName} RESTART IDENTITY;"
cursor.execute(sql.SQL(query).format(tableName=sql.Literal("person"))
```

Aside from prevent a whole host of safety issues, this style of formatting prevents SQL Injection attacks. Going forward, it's better to adopt this style or some of the other possible ones using built in `.format()`.

For further reading please check [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html).